# Flash AS3 PNGEncoder With Base64 and PHP Not Working

Tags: php, actionscript-3, base64

I am trying to utilize the PNGEncoder with the dynamicfash Base64 to send a Base64 String to PHP and save the PNG File but for some reason that i cannot figure out, the PNG file is never readable. It is there and has a size (contains data) but cannot be opened by anything so is not a valid png file. Here is my code...

```
var target:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
target.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000,5.0);
target.graphics.drawRect(0,0,100,100);
target.graphics.endFill();

var bdata:BitmapData = new BitmapData(100, 100);            
bdata.draw(target);  
var stream:ByteArray = PNGEncoder.encode(bdata);             
var byteArrayAsString:String = Base64.encodeByteArray(stream);

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("pngsave.php");
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
variables.fileName = "testing.png";
variables.image = byteArrayAsString;
request.data = variables;
navigateToURL(request, "_blank");
```

and the PHP Code...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$_POST['fileName']);

echo base64_decode($_POST["image"]);
?>
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: There are is no "AS3 PNGEncoder", nor "AS3 Base64".  What libraries are you using?  Some implementations of Base64 are different, sometimes there are markers at the beginning/end.

Comment: I'm using the AS3 PNGEncoder from the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) and the Base64 from  [dynamicflash.util](https://github.com/spjwebster/as3base64/blob/master/src/com/dynamicflash/util/Base64.as) Sorry I did not specify before.

Comment: If you do Base64.encode('test') and echo base64_encode('test'), do they return the same thing?

Comment: Yea they do.  So the decode should be decoding to the write format if the PNGEncoder is working... which according to many others online it is which is why I am puzzled.  Thanks for the idea to test that though.

Answer (score 0):

With FlashPlayer 10 (which has >95% adoption rate) you don't need to send the png data to a php page. Just use [`FileReference.save()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) instead.

Comment: I am doing that for now because I just want to open the file quickly to see if it was made correctly, but in the future I want to save it to the server... Can I still use the FileReference.save()? Also I am using CS3 so I don't seem to have a .save method.. is there anyway to update this or do I need to move up to CS4 or 5?